# Can only vote to close, can't vote to keep open

Tags: support

Looked at [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35204/which-airport-has-the-lowest-circling-mdh) from the Questions link, and saw that it had a "Close (1)" vote on it.  Looks like a valid (if not potentially earth-moving famous spectacular stellar) question to me, so typically I'd go to Review & vote to leave open.  But in this case, the Review queue didn't have any pending Close votes, so there was no option to vote to leave it open.

Did the fact that I'd first visited the question "normally" mean that it doesn't show up in my Review queue, and I could have voted to leave it open only if I'd first gone to review?

Or, does the fact that I did NOT click the "close(1)" link & vote to close there, accomplish the same thing as voting in Review to leave open?  I *thought* that if enough people voted to leave the question open, the vote-to-close option went away, but I may be mistaken there.  Yes? No?

Is there another reason that I didn't see that question in my Review queue?

Thanks

Comment: I know I've come across questions in the queue that I already visited, and if I had done something like comment of upvote, it would give me the "I'm done" option right away.

Comment: @fooot  That's what happens in reviewing a "First Post" but that's entirely different than where I was... just read the question as a question, and it never showed up in any review queue at all.  I would have expected it to show up in the "Close Votes" queue, but it didn't. The explanation Kevin gave below may explain why it didn't.

Comment: That's true... I think the close queue works the same way though. Next time you can check the review history to see if it's already been reviewed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, the close votes expire some 4 or 5 days after they're casted.

When one close vote is casted, it is put to the review queue. However, once enough people has reviewed it (either hit the Close or Leave Open buttons), it will be cleared from the queue. However the close votes already casted are not removed by the action of clearing the question from the queue; instead they will remain there until they expire.

To my knowledge, there is no option on Stack Exchange to actively vote to "Leave Open" a question.

Comment: Sounds like the implication here is that enough votes had already been cast to "Leave Open" that this question was no longer in the Review queue.  Seems to make sense, thanks.

Comment: @RalphJ yep, you can check the voting history here: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/close/history. the particular question is here: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/close/20409