# How does vote to close work?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Does it just keep asking until five people agree or does it ask ten times to get five votes or what? [This question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3198/can-only-vote-to-close-cant-vote-to-keep-open) doesn't answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A question stays in the close queue as long as there are close votes against it. Votes will expire if three users in review vote to leave open. If the question doesn't reach three "leave open" votes or 5 close votes:

- If the question has less than 100 views, the votes expire one per day after 14 days.
- If the question has more than 100 views, close votes expire at a rate of one per day, starting 4 days after the last vote was cast.

Sources from Meta:

[What is a "closed", “on hold”, or "duplicate" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question/10583#10583)

[Why do close votes expire?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120896/why-do-close-votes-expire)